# Some issues regarding the use of ”at a loss”

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

I came across the following sentence from a ”A study in scarlet” by Arthur Conan Doyle:

> We are *at a loss* as to how he came into the empty house; indeed, the whole affair is a puzzler.

I understand the meaning of *at a loss* idiom, both from the context that follows it and from the dictionary.
I wonder if I can emphasize it using the adverbs much or quite or any appropriate adverb for this context. Would there be valid English?

> We are much *at a loss* as to how...
>
> We are quite *at a loss* as to how...

Another instance would be the use of *at all*. I know from the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/at-all) that it is used to make negatives and questions stronger:

> He’s had no food at all.
>
> Why the universe ever existed at all?

Given the fact that *we are at a loss* looks like a positive but has a negative semantic I wonder if I can say:

> We are at a loss at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of emphasising *at a loss*:

> We are *quite* at a loss.

is OK, but more common is:

> We are at *quite* a loss.

You can use adverbs that mean completely, but only before *at*:

> I am completely at a loss.
>
> I am totally at a loss.

or their equivalent adjectives between *a* and *loss*, but this is less common:

> I am at a complete loss to explain...
>
> I am at a total loss to explain...

*Much* doesn't work with *at a loss* at all, as *much* refers to a quantity but you are either *at a loss* or you aren't.

As for *at a loss* and *at all*, they just don't go together. If you wanted to use *at all* in the original sentence you would have to rewrite it as something like:

> We have no idea *at all* as to how he came into the empty house; indeed, the whole affair is a puzzler.